# Reference to type 'IResourceGroups' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent', but it could not be found

Tags: azure

I am getting this error when trying to call azure.ResourceGroups.List() where azure is an instance of Iazure.

[project.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TsWn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a try to following code to get list of resources. I test it on my side, it works correctly. We also could use the Resources - [List By Resource Group Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/listbyresourcegroup) to do that.

I install [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/1.0.0) 1.0.0 as you and use console app to test. Here is my testing code:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var subscriptionId = "your_subscriptionId";
var azure = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
var resource = azure.ResourceGroups.ListAsync().Result;
```

[image]